# Spring Security Oauth2 AuthenticationSuccessEvent published at each request

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am using Spring Security Oauth2 to secure my Spring Boot REST app. I want to process some operation after a user login success and failure. The problem is each 
 time I send a request with the user bearer token, `AuthenticationSuccessEvent` is published even the user is already authenticated.

This handler is always called:

```
@Async
@EventListener( { AuthenticationSuccessEvent.class } )
public void listenAuthenticationSuccessEvent( AuthenticationSuccessEvent event ) {
    AbstractAuthenticationToken auth = (AbstractAuthenticationToken) event
            .getSource();
    log.info( "User connected: {}", auth.getName() );
}
```

Is it normal? I want it to be called once.

Thans for your help

Comment: Yes, it is normal. Every time you send `Authentication` header, you are logged in again. Don't send the `Authentication` header, if you don`t want to be logged in again.

Comment: How would you access a protected resource if you don’t send the Authentication header?

Comment: If use a session, your session is authenticated.

Comment: I disabled session, as it is full OAuth2 secured

Comment: Without a session, you have to login every request again. You need a stateful server, if you don't want to login again.

Comment: Right, so I must review my application :(

Comment: @akuma8 did you find the way how to handle it properly? Im facing the same behavior for the refresh_token OAuth flow

Comment: @MeetJoeBlack Unfortunately no, you have to deal with that. As @ dur said, it's a normal behavior so you have to find the best way to handle that event in your business code.

Answer (score 2):

The reason that *AuthenticationSuccessEvent* event is being called on every token/refresh_token by default (starting from Spring 5.x) is because *"Authorization: Basic clientID:clientSecret"* header is presented as part of token request thus request handled by *BasicAuthenticationFilter* as well that authenticates the client using corresponding *AuthenticationManager(ProviderManager)* (in addition to the *ProviderManager* that is responsible for the token auth) implementation.

Each *ProviderManager*, in turn, has *AuthenticationEventPublisher* dependency that is used for publishing different kinds of events, in our case(auth success), it is *eventPublisher.publishAuthenticationSuccess(result);*

By default *ProviderManager* uses *NullEventPublisher* that could be overridden using *ProviderManager#setAuthenticationEventPublisher* setter.

*ProviderManager* is created by *'AuthenticationManagerBuilder* that set corresponding  event publisher to it(if not null).

```
protected ProviderManager performBuild() throws Exception {
...
ProviderManager providerManager = new ProviderManager(authenticationProviders,
        parentAuthenticationManager);
...
if (eventPublisher != null) {
   providerManager.setAuthenticationEventPublisher(eventPublisher);
}
```

AuthenticationManagerBuilder is populated from *WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter* see *WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter#getHttp* method where you cand find the following line(that was added in Spring Security 5.x):

```
authenticationBuilder.authenticationEventPublisher(eventPublisher);
```

One of the approaches to override that default behavior is to implement corresponding BasicWebSecurityConfig(extending WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter or AuthorizationServerSecurityConfiguration) and set NullEventPublisher to the *'AuthenticationManagerBuilder* before *ProviderManager* creation:

```
@Configuration
@Order(-1)
public class BasicSecurityConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerSecurityConfiguration {
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    super.configure(http);

    // override default DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher to avoid excessive firing of
    // AuthenticationSuccessEvent on successful client credentials verification that passed in "Authorization: Basic clientId:clientSecret" header
    http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class).authenticationEventPublisher(new NullEventPublisher());
    http.httpBasic()
}

private static final class NullEventPublisher implements AuthenticationEventPublisher {
    public void publishAuthenticationFailure(AuthenticationException exception, Authentication authentication) {
    }

    public void publishAuthenticationSuccess(Authentication authentication) {
    }
}
}
```