# Setting a DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher in WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter for Spring Security 5

Tags: spring, spring-security

I've updated some of our services to Spring Security 5 from a SS 4 version where it had external support for OAuth2.  I've been able to update our services for the most part.

Previously our WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter had the following configure function where we set an applicationEventPublisher on a OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter so we can output logs messages about AuthenticationEvents.
But OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter went away in SS5 because OAuth2 support is now directly supported.
Is their an easier way of setting the AuthenticationEventPublisher without creating my own filter and recreating the part of checking authentication to just have it done again by Spring?

```
  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter filter = new OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter();
    filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    filter.setStateless(true);
    filter.setAuthenticationEventPublisher(
        new DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher(applicationEventPublisher));
    filter.afterPropertiesSet();

    http.csrf()
        .disable()
        .anonymous()
        .disable()
        .httpBasic()
        .disable()
        .logout()
        .disable()
        .formLogin()
        .disable()
        .addFilterBefore(filter, SessionManagementFilter.class)
        .antMatcher("/actuator/**")
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS)
        .permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/actuator/**")
        .access("#oauth2.hasScope('auditor')")
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated()
        .accessDecisionManager(accessDecisionManager);
  }

  @Bean
  public ApplicationListener<AuditApplicationEvent> onEventListener() {
    return (AuditApplicationEvent event) -> {
      LoggingUtil loggingFormat = new LoggingUtil();
      loggingFormat.setUser(event.getAuditEvent().getPrincipal());
      loggingFormat.setEvent("Resource Authentication");
      loggingFormat.setOutcome(event.getAuditEvent().getType());
      loggingFormat.setMessage(
          event.getAuditEvent().getData().containsKey("message")
              ? event.getAuditEvent().getData().get("message").toString()
              : "");
      String info = loggingFormat.toString();
      logger.info(info);
    };
  }
```

For our SS 5 we have

```
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        SessionManagementFilter as;

        //TODO how do we setup the authenticationEventPublisher
    //filter.setAuthenticationEventPublisher(
//        new DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher(applicationEventPublisher));

        http.csrf()
                .disable()
                .anonymous()
                .disable()
                .httpBasic()
                .disable()
                .logout()
                .disable()
                .formLogin()
                .disable()
//        .addFilterBefore(filter, SessionManagementFilter.class)
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS)
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/actuator/**").hasAuthority("SCOPE_auditor")
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2ResourceServer().jwt();
    }
```

Comment: did you find the way how to set AuthenticationEventPublisher implementation to the auth manager? since I found that in Spring 5 DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher is used by default instead of NullEventPublisher that results in AuthenticationSuccessEvent firing on each call since it contains Auth:Basic header

Comment: But does it fire by default for other authentication events?

Comment: pls check my answer there https://stackoverflow.com/a/60047580/2517384
I suppose that you can use http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class).authenticationEventPublisher(..) to set event publisher